# Contentedness of subspace Y of X in general case.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If Y is a subspace of X, a separation of Y is a pair of disjoint non-empty sets A and B whose union is Y.

From above statement, I am not sure whether pair of disjoint non-empty sets A, B are open sets in subspace of Y or they are open in X.

Comment: They can be open, closed or clopen, we don't know without more information.

Comment: Are you asking about  connectedness (not contentedness) of Y?

Comment: Yes I am just wondering whether If A,B(separation of Y) are open sets in X or Y

Comment: They are open in Y. But if you look closely, you'll see that since they are contained in Y, being open in X will imply that they are open in Y by the definition of subspace topology.

Comment: Hi, if Y=AUB is separation of Y, then A and B are open and closed in Y. However, if Y is not open in R, then it is not the case that A and B are open in X?

Comment: @jessie: That’s correct: if $Y$ is not open in $X$, at least one of $A$ and $B$ is not open in $X$.